# On browser back or forward button click, skip one history step

Tags: javascript

I'm using this snippet to create certain JavaScript behaviors when a user clicks "back" or "forward" buttons of HTML5-ready browsers:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
   // do something cool
}
```

I want to be able to skip one step in history, when a certain condition is met:

```
if (certain_condition) {
// skip one step and go straight to the next one
}
```

Is it possible, and if yes, how can this be done?

Comment: Are these "history steps" all assumed to be from the same domain?

Comment: and you want to do this only on a specific page or number of pages?

Comment: I want to be able to skip the page that has `?s=` in its URL, and nothing after that – whether I'm going forward or back in history!